# React native Scrollview doesn't work on android

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

I try to do a scrollview but it doesn't work. I tried flex: 1, flexGrow:1, add flex:1 to outer views, add contentContainerStyle={{ minHeight: '100%', }}> , but i couldn't make it work. I am new in react native and I don't know how to do except for reading docs and online answers. Why is this happening??

here is the code:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
     
     
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            minHeight: '100%',
          }}>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: darkBrown, fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
          <Text style={{color: 'red', fontSize: 30}}>TEXT</Text>
           
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
```

style for container

```
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: lightestBeige,
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't need `height: '100%'` and `width: "100%"` under container style.

Remove the `view` tag on the code.

Under `contentContainerStyle` replace `minHeight: '100%'` with `flexGrow: 1`

I hope it resolves.

Comment: I closed and reopened the program and it worked D:

Comment: That's great  

Answer (score 1):

`SafeAreaView` might be the problem here. Try to change it with normal `View`

Answer (score 0):

Change `<Text style={{color:"green"}}>` and in container style object `backgroundColor:"lightestBeige"` ...
Add some more Text tags when they will go out of screen then scroll starts working as of know there no need to scroll.
And for rendering more data use Flatlist do read about it.